# replace and and masking some characters numeric to char

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to replace and masking some character for example "5489888811178620" needs to be
"XXXXXXXXXXXX8620",
thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is some credit card number with a fixed length of 16 digits:

```
regexp_replace(col, '(\d{12})(\d{4})', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX\2')
```

This replaces the first 12 digits of a 16 digit number with X

Answer (score 0):

```
select LPAD('X', 12, 'X') || RIGHT('5489888811178620',4);
```